# Where did my money go after I sold bitcoins to BitZIZ into PayPal?

Tags: exchanges, theft, fraud

I am new to this and hate it. I had $2340 in US dollars to sell in bitcoins. I needed the cash desperately for rent and car payment and food, so went through BitZIZ to deposit the money into my PayPal account. I received an email that said the transaction was complete and the funds were in PayPal. No they weren't. They are gone. I have nothing in PayPal, so I guess I'm down and out. When I contacted BitZIZ many times, no answer. When I contacted PayPal they said nothing was sent to them so my balance is zero. I am heartbroken...NEVER AGAIN. This money meant the world to me

Comment: Unfortunately, this is coming a bit too late to do you any good,but: **Don't ever send bitcoin to anyone you don't completely trust.**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are [multiple](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/7cz0qf/bitzizcom_is_scam/) [cases](https://nz.trustpilot.com/review/bitziz.com) of other customers reporting the site as a scam, so it's likely you'll never get a response from them, unfortunately.

Because most cryptocurrency transactions are irreversible and often somewhat anonymous, it is important to first check the reputation of any entity you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to contact BitZIZ to get your money.

Comment: I tried a dozen times and will not respond, thanks anyway